# Number pad does not work in vim and less

Tags: keyboard, hardware, vi

I am working from an iMac running Yosemite and using [this](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MB110LL/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-english-usa?fnode=56) keyboard.  The number pad works in the terminal, but when I open `vim` or `less` it does not.

For example using `less`, if I type for the number `8`, I get `ESCOx`, not an `8`.  In vim 7.2 (in command mode), it inserts an `x`.  How do I fix this behavior? I got this keyboard specifically for the number pad.

Comment: As far as I know, that's a special "feature" of vim. It also happens on Linux too.

Comment: can anybody explay what are the features that are supposed to be enabled? I am curious about what would be a scenario where I would want this to be enabled

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using Terminal (not iTerm or others), there is a setting that might help. Turn off this setting (sorry, it's in german. But the location should be the same):

[image: Sorry for the german screenshot]

If you are using `iTerm`, there is at least a fix for `vim`: You can remap the keys to get this to work. Just add the following lines to your `~/.vimrc` (Create it, if it doesn't exist.)

```
inoremap <Esc>Oq 1
inoremap <Esc>Or 2
inoremap <Esc>Os 3
inoremap <Esc>Ot 4
inoremap <Esc>Ou 5
inoremap <Esc>Ov 6
inoremap <Esc>Ow 7
inoremap <Esc>Ox 8
inoremap <Esc>Oy 9
inoremap <Esc>Op 0
inoremap <Esc>On .
inoremap <Esc>OQ /
inoremap <Esc>OR *
inoremap <Esc>Ol +
inoremap <Esc>OS -
inoremap <Esc>OM <Enter>
```

Source: [a comment in the vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PuTTY_numeric_keypad_mappings).

Comment: This definitely solves the pain.  Evidently this is also answered [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6613968)

Comment: Glad it helped..

Comment: Something new in Terminal Preferences (Terminal 2.7.3, Sierra) next to that checkbox is a message indicating that Num Lock (which is mapped from Keypad Clear by default) can be used to enter digits while application mode is active.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using iTerm and I correctly understood your question, in iTerm2 there is an appropriate preference:

http://www.twistermc.com/39930/use-number-pad-vim-iterm2/